# SQLite programming wont create Databases folder

Tags: sqlite

Im a noob in SQlite and android things.
Therefore, i happened to find this problem, somehow i cant create database folder.
Here is the code i used from tutorial in site :

```
package com.example.test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class haha extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Haha (Email VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR, LastName VARCHAR);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Haha VALUES('haha.com','anita','bobo');");
    db.close();
}
}
```

and here is what i got :
-no databases folder, i used DDMS
-data/data/com.example.test/ (only cache and lib folder exist)

any solution ??

Comment: Any interesting in the logcat ?

Comment: it says :error opening trace file: No cush file or directory (2)

Comment: oh and one more : Emulator without GPU emulation detected

Comment: That could be anything. Look if there is somethng interesting when your code executes (put a log.v() before and after your code).

Comment: this is my first time to hear that...

Comment: no luck ...... i spent a whole day, and i still dont know the problem

Comment: I tried your code with `/mnt/sdcard/downloads/MyDB` with emulator Android 4.0 and it works for me. It won't write to the current working directory (/ in my case).

Comment: I tried that, and when i clicked the sdcard folder, there is nothing to display..... no downloads folder.....Thx for your suggestion anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an absolute path

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("/data/data/com.example.test/MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

or

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyDB",
MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Information. I solved this problem myself.
I dont know exactly what is the problem, but
CHANGE YOUR ADT BUNDLE will SOLVED this...
I'm using adt bundle 20130522 before, but then
i change to adt bundle 20130717. 
And it works... Good Luck !!!!